# compile time check using instanceof

Tags: java, javac, instanceof

For the below code,

```
package java_instanceof;

        /*
         *                   
         *                     Object                  I0 
         *   I1    I2         ^        \              . ^
         *     .    .         |         \           .   |
         *       .   .        |          \ ______ .     |
         *         .  .       C1          |__B___|     I3
         *           . .     /                      .        
         *             ..   /                   .            
         *               C2                  .              
         *                ^               .                                    
         *                |            .                   
         *                |        .                      
         *                |    .
         *                C3 
         *                                           
         */ 

interface I0{}; interface I1{}; interface I2 {};
interface I3 extends I0{};

class C1{}; class B implements I0{};
class C2 extends C1 implements I1, I2 {}
class C3 extends C2 implements I3 {}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Object o;  Object[]  oa;
        I0    i0;  I0[]      i0a;
        I1    i1;  I1[]      i1a; 
        I2    i2;  I2[]      i2a;
        I3    i3;  I3[]      i3a;
        C1    c1;  C1[]      c1a;
        C2    c2;  C2[]      c2a;
        C3    c3;  C3[]      c3a;
        B     b;   B[]        ba;

        //Compile time check
        boolean value1 = c3 instanceof B;  //compile time check error
        boolean value2 = b instanceof C3;  // compile time check error


    }

}
```

As a beginner, I would like to know, How is `javac` able to raise compile time error `Incompatible conditional operand type`? Is the complete class hierarchy known at compile time?

Comment: "Is the class hierarchy known at compile time?" - well, yes, what did you expect?

Comment: You can read up on [compile time exceptions in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. Of course the class hierarchy of all classes and interfaces in the compiled file and in files imported by it are known at compile time. However, at run-time there could be additional classes and interfaces.

In your case however, both `C3` and `B` are classes, and then the available information is enough to determine that `c3` can never refer to an instance of `B`, and `b` can never refer to an instance of `C3`. This is the case because classes inherit from a single (or, in the case of `Object`, no) superclass.

With interfaces the situation is different. The following fragment will not lead to a compile time error:

```
I1 i1 = ... ;
boolean v = i1 instanceof B;
```

because someone might declare a subclass of `B` which also implements `I1`.

Comment: Adding another `class D` to above, `class D extends B implements I1{};B b = new D();value = b instanceof I2;` this should give `false` at runtime. but why compiler is not able to find `incompatible operand type` error at compile time?

Comment: To decide whether an compiler error is to be displayed, the compiler only looks at the types of the `instanceof` operator. Someone might define a subclass of `D` which also implements `I2`, and therefore `b instanceof I2` does not result in a compiler error.

Comment: So, basic point is multiple subclass can implement interface, so compiler keeps quiet when you provide interface type as right operand, correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**! off course, The hierarchy, may it be "implements" or "extends" etc is known at the compile time.

Without these checks, you cannot take advantage of OOPS even while programming further into the tree of relations that you are trying to code.

Consider an example of **Object** Class itself, if Object was not the parent of all class, you might not have been able to Override the *toString(), hashcode(), clone()* methods that basically come from Object Class. So you get these methods in intellisence of any IDE, hence these are already pre-compiled before even execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Compiler first looks in the method's lexical hierarchy, then in the class hierarchy, and finally, in the global scope. for more related information on how compiler works you can refer Book "Engineering a Compiler" by Keith Cooper- Method and class Invocation topic.

for your first question you may find this http://codereply.com/answer/42s61x/instanceof-incompatible-conditional-operand-types.html helpful.